# Automapper.Initialize method not found

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, automapper

I'm creating simple MVC app where I want to use Automapper.
I've installed in my project, configure profile like this :

```
public class ExportProfile : Profile
{
    public ExportProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Export, ExportDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Local, LocalDto>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Then I'd like to go to: Global.asax

`Mapper.Initialize( x => x.AddProfile<ExportProfile>() )`;

And then I get: 'Mapper' does not contain a definition for 'Initialize'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/9.0-Upgrade-Guide.html

Answer (score 1):

In .NET core you can use the following Extension in startup to configure Automapper Services use NuGet package:

**AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection**

Registration Code

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(EntityToViewModelProfile).Assembly);
```

As far as I can see you are not using .NET core, because you have Global.asax file. So you can either check the above extension method content by following the link:
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

Or you can use the following configuration:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
  cfg.AddMaps(typeof(EntityToViewModelProfile).Assembly);
});
```

And resolve IMapper interface based on IOC container you are using with the following instantiation method:

```
IMapper mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
```

Here is an example of this type configuration using Autofac:

```
builder.Register<IConfigurationProvider>(c => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddMaps(typeof(EntityToViewModelProfile).Assembly);
})).SingleInstance();
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IConfigurationProvider>().CreateMapper()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Answer (score -1):

`Mapper.Initialize( x => x.AddProfile<ExportProfile>() )`  is obsolete.

You can use the Mapper directly into your controller class like I did here:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Customer,CustomerDTO>());
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
return context.Customers.ToList().Select(mapper.Map<Customer, CustomerDTO>);
```